# Cumulative SQL to work out no of payers

Tags: sql-server-2008, inner-join

Currently trying to create a query that shows how many accounts have paid month on month but on a cumulative basis (penetration). So as an example I have a table with Month paid and account number, which shows what month that account paid.

```
Month  | AccountNo
Jan-14 | 123456
Feb-14 | 321654
```

So using the above the result set would show

```
Month  | Payers
Jan-14 | 1
Feb-14 | 2
```

being because one account paid in Jan, then one in Feb meaning that there have been by the end of Feb 2 payments overall, but only one in Jan. Tried a few `inner joins` back onto the table itself with a `t1.Month >= t2.Month` as i would for a normal cumulative query but the result is always out.

Any questions please ask, unsure if the above will be clear to anyone but me.

Comment: I may help- http://www.orafaq.com/node/1874 .

Comment: Do you have a date field in this table?

Comment: @KiranHegde I can add it in if needed yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have date in the table then you can try the following query.

```
SELECT [Month]
      ,(SELECT COUNT(AccountNo) 
        FROM theTable i
        -- This is to make sure to add until the last day of the current month.
        WHERE i.[Date] <= DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,o.[Date])+1,0)) AS CumulativeCount

FROM theTable o
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, several things. You need to have an actual date field, as you can't order by the month column you have.

You need to consider there may be gaps in the months - i.e. some months where there is no payment (not sure if that is true or not)

I'd recommend a recursive common table expression to do the actual aggregation

Heres how it works out:

```
-- setup
DECLARE @t TABLE ([Month] NCHAR(6), AccountNo INT)
INSERT @t ( [Month], AccountNo )
VALUES  ( 'Jan-14',123456),('Feb-14',456789),('Apr-14',567890) 
-- assume no payments in march

; WITH 
t2 AS     -- get a date column we can sort on
(
    SELECT [Month], 
       CONVERT(DATETIME, '01 ' + REPLACE([Month], '-',' '), 6) AS MonthStart, 
       AccountNo
    FROM @t
), 
t3 AS          -- group by to get the number of payments in each month
(
    SELECT [Month], MonthStart, COUNT(1) AS PaymentCount FROM t2 
    GROUP BY t2.[Month], t2.MonthStart
),
 t4 AS          -- get a row number column to order by (accounting for gaps)
(
    SELECT [Month], MonthStart, PaymentCount, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MonthStart) AS rn FROM t3 
), 
t5 AS          -- recursive common table expression to aggregate subsequent rows
(
    SELECT [Month], MonthStart, PaymentCount AS CumulativePaymentCount, rn 
    FROM t4 WHERE rn = 1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT t4.[Month], t4.MonthStart, 
      t4.PaymentCount + t5.CumulativePaymentCount AS CumulativePaymentCount, t4.rn
    FROM t5 JOIN t4 ON t5.rn + 1 = t4.rn
)
SELECT [Month], CumulativePaymentCount FROM t5 -- select desired results
```

and the results...

```
Month   CumulativePaymentCount 
Jan-14  1 
Feb-14  2 
Apr-14  3
```

Answer (score 0):

If your month column is date type then its easy to work on else you need some additional conversion for it. Here the query goes...

```
create table example (
MONTHS datetime,
  AccountNo INT
  )
GO

insert into example values  ('01/Jan/2009',300345)
insert into example values  ('01/Feb/2009',300346)
insert into example values  ('01/Feb/2009',300347)
insert into example values  ('01/Mar/2009',300348)
insert into example values  ('01/Feb/2009',300349)
insert into example values  ('01/Mar/2009',300350)


SELECT   distinct datepart (m,months),
    (SELECT count(accountno) 
    FROM example b 
    WHERE datepart (m,b.MONTHS) <= datepart (m,a.MONTHS)) AS Total FROM example a
```